# A word for "life experiences"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a word that has the same meaning as "life experiences."

I tried to use *legend,* but I think it is too big for an individual person like me.

Comment: *experiences* because isn't life redundant?

Comment: That would really be the [ultimate question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aboZctrHfK8), but it has already [been asked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) and [answered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Answer (score 1):

The collection of one's life experiences, incidentally, is called "life."

*life* (TFD):

> **4** The physical, mental, and spiritual experiences that constitute existence.

Words often have narrower and broader meanings, different meanings from different perspectives, and  so on. Sentence construction and context generally help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think [knowledge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Knowledge) can express the concept: ( from TFD)

> - Familiarity, awareness, or understanding gained through experience or study
> - Facts, information, and skills acquired through experience or education.

Answer (score 0):

(Personal) *background* is one possibility.  (Personal) *history* is another.

It's not very clear just what you are looking for. Try to formulate a sentence that expresses what you want to say, and put "**____**" in place of the missing word.

Answer (score -2):

*inculcation*

> noun. the act of inculcating, or teaching or influencing **persistently and repeatedly** so as to implant or instill an idea, theory, attitude, etc.